# How can I make jQuery's $.each() function skip certain objects based on criteria?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<p class="link"><a href="#">This is a link.</a></p>
<p class="link"><a href="#">This is another link.</a></p>
<p class="link current"><a href="#">This is yet another link.</a></p>
<p class="link"><a href="#">This is still another link.</a></p>
```

I want to use jQuery's `$.each()` function to go through all the objects with the class `link`, but I want to skip the one which also has a class `current`. How do I do that?

I could check for the existence of the class within the each loop like this:

```
$('.link').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('current'))
        $(this).fadeOut();
})
```

... but is there a way to specify "class x, but not class y" in jQuery, removing the need for the if condition?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exclude the elements using the [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('.link:not(.current)').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) your initial jQuery object:

```
$('.link').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).hasClass('current');
}).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Interesting, but it still looks too complicated compared to the method I've mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.link').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class')!="link current")
        $(this).fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as using .hasClass(), which seems neater!

Answer (score 0):

As Guffa suggested, you can use `:not()` CSS pseudo-selector. To use it for `.each()` function, you can do the following (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDJqE/1/) as a proof):

```
jQuery(".link:not(.current)").each(function(index, element){
    jQuery(element).fadeOut();
});
```

Does it suit your needs?

Comment: Turns out I didn't need .each() because the selector gets all the objects anyway! Thanks!

Comment: @aalaap: Yes, the selector gets all the objects in both cases :) The only difference is when you need to do something complex (using `.each()`) or simple (applying jQuery's function on all the elements - in this case `.fadeOut()`) :)